# nginx перехватить редирект

Tags: nginx

У нас в учебном заведении провайдер блокирует определенные сайты(что то по типу родительского контроля, но для учебных заведений), но вместо показа заглушки он редиректит на главную страницу своего сайта. Руководство поставило задачу показывать сообщение что сайт заблокирован, а не просто показывать сайт провайдера.

У меня есть локальный веб-сервер на apache + nginx, но я не могу сообразить, как мне перехватить 301 редирект на сайт провайдера и показать вместо него страницу?

Просто портмапинг IP сайта провайдера не вариант, т.к. на этом IP еще локальные ресурсы есть(почта, файлообменник) которые должны работать.

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в учебном заведении нет своего прокси, который стоит между учебным классом и провайдером?

Comment: нет, используем NAT на Микротик RB2011UAS

Comment: Не в курсе про возможности этого роутера, но на вскидку я решал бы задачу так: 1. Мы знаем, что редирект происходит на стороне провайдера; 2. Нам необходимо где-то (на свой проксе, роутере, etc) определить, что произошел редирект; 3. Определить "значение" редиректа - если это редирект на страницу провайдера, то считаем, что произошел редирект по причине блокировки и делаем уже свой редирект на нашу страничку, остальные редиректы игнорируем. Как-то так.

Comment: ну так проблема и состоит в том как определить редирект.
я перенаправляю все запросы на наш локальный веб-сервер и на нём нужно нужно посмотреть куда провайдер послал...

Comment: Я уже плохо представляю, что у вас за "инфраструктура". _я перенаправляю все запросы на наш локальный веб-сервер_ - вы таки сделали из веб-сервера прокси? Или как это понимать?

Comment: я пока ничего не делал.
Но предполагаю что так нужно сделать...

Comment: Если вы завернете весь трафик на Apache/Nginx, то вам придется из них сделать прокси-сервер, и уже их средствами решать данную задачу. Думаю, что технически такое реализовать можно, по крайней мере у вас появится возможность отлавливать редиректы.